# command button is being renamed

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

I am having an issue with active x control command buttons being **renamed** in Word 2007 without the user actually renaming them.  I have directly observed the user saving the document with embedded active x controls and the names appear to be okay when they open the document, but when they save the document, they are renamed.

For example, the name property for CommandButton11 will be renamed to CommandButton111.  In some cases it appears that 1 is being added to the end of the Command Button Name so 10 becomes 101, while in other cases 1 is being added to the actual value of the command button so say CommandButton10 becomes CommandButton11.  The code for the command buttons does not change, but because I reference the names of the individual command buttons within the code, it obviously breaks.

The purpose of the code is to embed an OLE object in the document and place it correctly in a table.

Below is the specific code for the command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton10_Click()

wrdTbl = 1
wrdRow = 11
wrdCol = 2
Set obj = CommandButton10

Call buttontransformer

End Sub
```

Button transformer is as follows:

```
Private Sub buttontransformer()
    If ActiveDocument.Tables(wrdTbl).Cell(wrdRow, wrdCol).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
    obj.Caption = "Remove File"
        Call OLEObjectAdd
Else
    ActiveDocument.Tables(wrdTbl).Cell(wrdRow, wrdCol).Select
    Selection.EndKey unit:=wdRow, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete
obj.Caption = "Click to Add File"
ireply = MsgBox("Add another file?", buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="UPLOAD NEW FILE?")
    If ireply = vbYes Then
        obj.Caption = "Remove File"
        Call OLEObjectAdd
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

And OleObjectAdd is as follows:

```
Private Sub OLEObjectAdd()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim ofd As Variant
Dim FP As String
Dim FN As String
Dim Ext As String
Dim fType As String

'Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
ActiveDocument.Tables(wrdTbl).Cell(wrdRow, wrdCol + 1).Select

With fd
.ButtonName = "Select"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each ofd In .SelectedItems
    FP = ofd
    Debug.Print FP
    FN = Right(FP, Len(FP) - InStrRev(FP, "\"))
    Debug.Print FN
    Ext = Right(FP, Len(FP) - InStrRev(FP, "."))
    Debug.Print Ext
    Next ofd
    On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

If Ext = "pdf" Then
    fType = "adobe.exe"
ElseIf Ext = "doc" Or Ext = "docx" Or Ext = "docm" Then
    fType = "word.exe"
ElseIf Ext = "xls" Or Ext = "xlsx" Or Ext = "xlsm" Then
    fType = "Excel.exe"
End If

Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:=fType, _
    fileName:=FP, LinkToFile:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
    fType, IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
    FN

Selection.Move unit:=wdCell, Count:=-2
Selection = FN


End Sub
```

I had done the Microsoft Fixit to address the Active-X broken controls and it works fine on several other computers I have tested this on.

I have searched high and low for an answer and cant seem to find one.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this on MS website, but was wondering if anyone had a workaround yet?

Another behavior has been reported concerning the default naming of a control. A '2' is getting concatenated in the name causing for example, the Command Button to create the first control as CommandButton21 rather than CommandButton1.  

This issue is also being reviewed.